# How code be this piece of code be refactored?

Tags: d

I use DMD 1.056 with Tango 0.99.9 to build a GPX document using API. I am a beginner in D language.

---

Usage DMD 1.056 with Tango 0.99.9 is compulsory as a requirement

The GPX data are here hardcoded but my intent is to write a more high level GPX builder code using appropriate API.

---

**The piece of code to refactor:**

```
module SwathGen;

import 
  tango.io.Stdout,
  tango.text.xml.Document,
  tango.text.xml.DocPrinter;

void main(char[][] args)
{   
    auto gpxdoc = new Document!(char);

    gpxdoc.header;

    gpxdoc.tree 
        .element(null,"gpx")
      .attribute (null,"xmlns","http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1")
      .attribute (null,"version","1.1")
            .attribute (null,"creator","SwathGen")
      .attribute (null,"xmlns:xsi","http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
      .attribute (null,"xsi:schemaLocation","http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd http://www.topografix.com/GPX/gpx_style/0/2 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/gpx_style/0/2/gpx_style.xsd http://www.topografix.com/GPX/gpx_overlay/0/3 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/gpx_overlay/0/3/gpx_overlay.xsd")
  ;

  gpxdoc.elements
        .element (null,"metadata")
      .element(null,"name","JobDef.gpx")

      .parent
      .element(null,"desc","Spray Job")

      .parent
      .element(null,"author")
        .element (null,"name","izylay")

        .parent
        .element (null,"email")
          .attribute (null,"id","izylay")
          .attribute (null,"domain","ary.com")

        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"copyright")
        .attribute (null,"author","izylay")
        .element (null,"year","2011")

        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"time","2011-10-10T08:19:50Z")

      .parent
      .element(null,"keywords","ULM, J300, Aerial Spraying, Locust")

      .parent
            .element (null,"bounds")
        .attribute (null,"minlat","-18.85522622")
                .attribute (null,"minlon","47.37275913")
                .attribute (null,"maxlat","-18.82044444")
                .attribute (null,"maxlon","47.39838002")
    ;

    gpxdoc.elements     
        .element(null,"wpt")
      .attribute (null,"lat","-18.85522622")
      .attribute (null,"lon","47.39173757")

      .element (null,"name","A000")

      .parent
      .element (null,"sym","Waypoint")
  ;

    gpxdoc.elements     
        .element(null,"rte")
      .element (null,"name","Spray Job")
      //
      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.85522610")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.39838002")
        .element (null,"name","Entry point")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.85522525")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.37275913")
        .element (null,"name","B000")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.85387012")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.37275913")
        .element (null,"name","B001")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent


      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.85387109")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.39173757")
        .element (null,"name","A001")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.85251596")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.39173757")
        .element (null,"name","A002")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.85251499")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.37275913")
        .element (null,"name","B002")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.85115986")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.37275913")
        .element (null,"name","B003")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.85116082")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.39173757")
        .element (null,"name","A003")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.84980569")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.39173757")
        .element (null,"name","A004")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.84980472")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.37275913")
        .element (null,"name","B004")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.84844959")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.37275913")
        .element (null,"name","B005")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.84845056")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.39173757")
        .element (null,"name","A005")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.84709543")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.39173757")
        .element (null,"name","A006")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.84709446")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.37275913")
        .element (null,"name","B006")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.84573933")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.37275913")
        .element (null,"name","B007")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.84574029")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.39173757")
        .element (null,"name","A007")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.84438516")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.39173757")
        .element (null,"name","A008")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.84438419")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.37275913")
        .element (null,"name","B008")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.84302906")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.37275913")
        .element (null,"name","B009")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.84303003")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.39173757")
        .element (null,"name","A009")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.84167489")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.39173757")
        .element (null,"name","A010")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.84167393")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.37275913")
        .element (null,"name","B010")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.84031879")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.37275913")
        .element (null,"name","B011")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.84031976")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.39173757")
        .element (null,"name","A011")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.83896463")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.39173757")
        .element (null,"name","A012")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.83896366")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.37275913")
        .element (null,"name","B012")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.83760852")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.37275913")
        .element (null,"name","B013")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.83760949")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.39173757")
        .element (null,"name","A013")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.83625436")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.39173757")
        .element (null,"name","A014")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.83625339")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.37275913")
        .element (null,"name","B014")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.83489825")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.37275913")
        .element (null,"name","B015")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.83489922")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.39173757")
        .element (null,"name","A015")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.83354409")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.39173757")
        .element (null,"name","A016")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.83354312")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.37275913")
        .element (null,"name","B016")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.83218798")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.37275913")
        .element (null,"name","B017")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.83218895")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.39173757")
        .element (null,"name","A017")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.83083382")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.39173757")
        .element (null,"name","A018")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.83083285")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.37275913")
        .element (null,"name","B018")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.82947771")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.37275913")
        .element (null,"name","B019")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.82947868")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.39173757")
        .element (null,"name","A019")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.82812355")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.39173757")
        .element (null,"name","A020")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.82812258")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.37275913")
        .element (null,"name","B020")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.82676744")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.37275913")
        .element (null,"name","B021")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.82676841")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.39173757")
        .element (null,"name","A021")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent

      .parent
      .element(null,"rtept")
        .attribute (null,"lat","-18.82044444")
        .attribute (null,"lon","47.39173757")
        .element (null,"name","Exit point")
        .parent
        .element (null,"sym","Dot")
        .parent
    ;

    gpxdoc.elements     
        .element(null,"extensions") 
      .element(null,"polyline")
        .attribute(null,"xmlns","http://www.topografix.com/GPX/gpx_overlay/0/3")

        .element(null,"points")
          //
          .element(null,"pt")   
            .attribute (null,"lat","-18.85522622")
            .attribute (null,"lon","47.37275913")

          .parent
          .element(null,"pt")   
            .attribute (null,"lat","-18.85522622")
            .attribute (null,"lon","47.39838002")

          .parent
          .element(null,"pt")   
            .attribute (null,"lat","-18.82044444")
            .attribute (null,"lon","47.39838002")

          .parent
          .element(null,"pt")   
            .attribute (null,"lat","-18.82044444")
            .attribute (null,"lon","47.37275913")

          .parent
          .element(null,"pt")   
            .attribute (null,"lat","-18.85522622")
            .attribute (null,"lon","47.37275913")
          //
    ;
    auto print = new DocPrinter!(char);

    Stdout(print(gpxdoc)).newline;  
}
```

---

**Question:**

How could it be improved ?

Comment: why are you building this XML file in D, rather then loading it?

Comment: @Winston Ewert: You are right. Load and parse is the best way to go given an XML file, But I am begining D1/Tango and try to devise a way to build XML using API manipulation and must recognize that hardcoding it as I did is misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, there is a lot of data in your program. As Cygal points out, you should put this where it belongs - in a data file.

Other than that, there are lots of this instructions in your code:

```
  .element(null,"rtept")
    .attribute (null,"lat","-18.82812258")
    .attribute (null,"lon","47.37275913")
    .element (null,"name","B020")
    .parent
    .element (null,"sym","Dot")
    .parent
```

I would put that in a single function.

```
.append(createDot(gpxdoc, "-18.82812258", "47.37275913", "B020")).parent
.append(createDot(gpxdoc, "-18.82676744", "47.37275913", "B021")).parent
```

Since I've never used this language I leave the implementation of the `createDot` function to you.

**Edit**: Now I understand your intent a little better. You want to do something like this:

```
auto gpxdoc = new GPXDocument;

gpxdoc
    .setDesc("Spray Job")
    .setAuthor("izylay", "izylay@ary.com")
    .setCopyright("izylay", "2011")
    .setKeywords("ULM", "Aerial Spraying", "Locust")
    .setBounds("-18.85522622", "47.37275913", "-18.82044444", "47.39838002")

    .addWaypoint("A000", "-18.85522622", "47.39173757")

    .addEntrypoint("-18.85522610", "47.39838002")

    .addPoint("B000", "-18.85522525", "47.37275913")
    .addPoint("B001", "-18.85387012", "47.37275913")
```

You can inherit the Document object and add all these methods just to be wrappers around normal node manipulation.

The thing with fluent interfaces is that they may maintain state (that's why you need a `parent` method, for example.) I'm not familiar with the gpx format, but I wouldn't be surprised if you can create groups of points. For that case, you just need to store a "state" reference. For the top-level attributes or elements (description, etc.) you can store references to the appropriate node.

Hope this points you to the right direction.

Comment: +1: Thank you for pointing mee to this direction. Now, I think of extending the Document class and try to find a way to include a kind of createdoc using fluent interface.

Answer (score 1):

Store this data in an XML file and parse it using [std.xml](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_xml.html).

Tango also has had an [XML parser](http://www.dsource.org/projects/tango/wiki/TutXmlPath) for years which is  [reputed](http://dotnot.org/blog/archives/2008/03/12/why-is-dtango-so-fast-at-parsing-xml/) to be [very fast](http://dotnot.org/blog/archives/2008/03/10/xml-benchmarks-parsequerymutateserialize/). Use that instead. :)

Comment: Thank you for answering. I forgot to mention it and I have to make an edit: I must stick to the Tango library.

Comment: I want to devise something building a GPX document using API but not parsing a GPX file.

Comment: Tango also has an XML parser. I can't recommend enough to use that instead.

Comment: Tango's XML parser is defined in the module `tango.text.xml.Document` and I already use it in my piece of code.

Comment: Yeah, but you can use Document.parse and tango.io.device.File to get the tango document from an actual file. Do you understand what I mean? If you don't want to do it, that's fine, but I'd like to make sure my answer was clear.

Comment: Your answer is clear indeed: You suggest me to load and parse a file so as to build an XML document in memory but that will defeat  my intent seeking for code allowing me to build in memory an XML Document using API manipulation (presumably without a prior XML file as you assumed). Maybe hardcoding the GPX data in my piece of code is misleading and I have to recognize that.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Yes, I think it is misleading, and it's difficult to answer without knowing about what the API gives you. :( Maybe this approach is perfect with the API, maybe it's not: hard to tell!

Comment: +1: I end up succeeding parsing the content of a GPX file casting it beforehand >>> `auto gpxcontent = cast(char[]) file.load(file)` <<<. Enfin un petit progrès pour moi même si c'est dans une autre direction. Merci bien, j'apprécie votre aide